# Add value from a form into a function

Tags: php, ajax

I have the following form:

```
<form action="myform.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  <input type="hidden" name="my-add-calc" value="add to cart" class="button" />
          <input id="my-item-calc" name="my-item-calc" value="29.00">
         <input type="hidden" name="my-item-id" value="1"></td>
      <td><input  type="submit"></form>
```

I want to use the submitted value of my-item-calc in a function:

I have tried

```
public function add_calc($calcdel){
    $validCaldel = false;
           if (is_numeric($calcdel)){
        $validCaldel= true;}
//add calculated delivery
    if ($validCaldel !==false){

        $this->calcdels = $calcdel;}
    }
```

Where

$calcdel = $config['calc']['calcdel'];

in the config file:

```
$config['checkoutPath']           = 'myform.php';
$config['calc']['calcdel']        = 'my-item-calc';
```

When I try to return $this->caldels its says this is an array, Im not sure why as I am only adding one value.
I would want the `$this->calcdels` to echo out the submitted 29.00

Any help very welcome

Comment: Could you share the code where you get the posted form value?

Comment: this I think where the problem lies as Im not sure how to get the form value I have tried return $calc['calcdel'] but no joy there

Comment: _“in the config file:: `$config['calc']['calcdel']        = 'my-item-calc';`“_ - and that is supposed to achieve what, exactly? Where are you calling your `add_calc` function?

Comment: I have tried to call it like if($_POST[$calcadd]) $calcAdded = $this->add_calc($calcdel); if ($calcAdd = true){$tis-calcdels = $calcdel;

Comment: try with var_dump($_POST) to see which fields you have submitted

Comment: `$calcdel`, `$calcdels`, `$validCaldel`, suggest using variable names less susceptible to create havoc (in your question you also misspelled _`$this->caldels`_ which should be `$this->calcdels`

Comment: ["my-add-calc"]=> string(11) "add to cart" ["my-item-calc"]=> string(5) "29.00" ["my-item-id"]=> string(1) "1"  is echoed back

Answer (score 0):

In your myform.php you shoud first get the value you're looking for:

```
$my_item_calc = $_POST[ 'my-item-calc' ];
```

and then give it to the function:

```
add_calc( $my_item_calc );
```